# Aggregating in R to calculate the sum of one column and further dividing by the number of trials

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks similar to this

```
TRIAL      ProbeState      RecallType      SaccadeAmplitude     
1          digits          backwards       0.45 
1          digits          forwards        0.21    
1          positions       backwards       1.40         
1          positions       forwards        0.90        
2          digits          backwards       1.23         
2          positions       forwards        1.01
3          digits          backwards       0.10 
3          digits          forwards        0.34
3          positions       backwards       1.50
3          positions       forwards        1.78
3          positions       forwards        0.88
3          positions       forwards        0.56
```

I would like to sum up all the saccadic amplitudes in a trial, and divide by the number rows per trial.

So for instance: 0.45 + 0.21 + 1.40 + 0.90 = 2.96.

2.96 / 4 = 0.74

Would the following be appropriate?

```
AmplitudeByTrial = aggregate(SaccadeAmplitude ~ TRIAL + ProbeState + RecallType, data=MergedData, mean)
```

I am worried that FUN = mean may not recognise that the number of rows for each trial differs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

your_data %>% 
  group_by(TRIAL) %>% 
  summarise(AmplitudeByTrial = sum(SaccadeAmplitude) / n())
```